# SwiftUI: Creating a Pull-down menu

Tags: swift, menu, swiftui, ios14

in the [HIG Apple writes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/): *In iOS 14 and later, a button can display a pull-down menu that lists items or actions from which people can choose*

This is exactly what I want for my project. [This picture](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/images/menu-secondary-actions.png) where they have a "more" bar button with a drop-down menu fits the bill perfectly. Does anyone have an example, though, of how to create a pull-down menu (not context-menu) from a button with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Menu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) view that is new for iOS in iOS 14.

It acts as a button and when pressed presents the context menu. You can use a `Label` if you want an image and even nest different views, as shown in the
example in the documentation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Hello World"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
                .navigationTitle("Hello")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: {
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: { text = "Hello there" }) {
                            Label("Hello", systemImage: "pencil")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                    
                }())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Instead of `navigationBarItems` one should probably use `toolbar`, however I found that to be quite unreliable starting with Beta 4.

---

[image: An example menu]

Comment: In the HIG linked by the original poster, it shows a selection checkmark next to one of the menu items. I don't see how that can be done in SwiftUI. Have you had any luck with that?

Comment: @hayesk Way easier than expected. Just use a `Picker`.

Comment: @jlsiewert thanks! Now if only I can get macOS to draw it the same way. macOS puts the image and then a popup menu button beside it.